# How to test if DNS information has propagated?

Tags: domain-name-system

I set up a new DNS entry for one of my subdomains (I haven't set up any Apache virtual hosts or anything like that yet). How can I check that the DNS information has propagated?

I assumed that I could simply `ping my.subdomain.com` and assume that if it could resolve, it would show the IP address I specified in the A record. However, I don't know if I am assuming correctly. What is the best way to check this information?

Comment: Not a dumb question. It's not that straight forward to find out this kind of thing.

Comment: I agree with @aseq that this is not a *dumb* question, but "try it and see" would have given you the answer too. It's also something Google could answer just as easily with the littlest bit of effort (search for `How to test if DNS information has propagated` -- the bloody *question title* generates good Google results).

Comment: @voretaq7 - sorry for not giving the full backstory. I already tried pinging the address but would not resolve the IP even though it had been days which made me think I was doing something wrong. Also, It's hard to test everything while doing this from your phone, and rather than rolling the dice with google I prefer to get advice directly from professionals in the field. Sorry if I wasted anyone's time by posting this question before consulting the Google.

Comment: I don't think you wasted people's time. Your question provoked some valuable responses. You never know how a seemingly simple question that could "just be googled" may turn out. One of the values of this forum is that the answers and questions can be expanded upon very easily.

Comment: @andrew nothing wrong with asking what a lot of us view as simple questions - this will probably be the top google result for that string in a few days because of how the site gets indexed/ranked. In general though Google is a better (faster) place to look: If Google doesn't know then ask here (and Google will learn) :-)

Comment: I figured out why nothing I was trying was working. Apparently, our network is configured in a way that a new subdomain must be added in our local DNS too. So the subdomain was accessible from the outside world, just not in our network where I was testing. =[ But using `nslookup` and `dig` while specifying an external server made it so I could verify the external DNS information.

Comment: Andrew: Glad you got it figured out. To reiterate what aseq stated, your question wasn't a waste of time and you got some very good insight into DNS. We may not all agree with each other but your question sparked some intelligent answers and comments that hopefully give you a little better understanding of DNS.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use dig or nslookup, say your (or your provider's if you don't run your own) nameserver is ns1.example.com.

Using nslookup:

```
nslookup - ns1.example.com
```

At prompt type:

```
my.example.com
```

If it resolves to what you expected then it works. It should give you something like:

```
Name:   example.com
Address: 192.0.43.10
```

It may still take a while to propagate to the rest of the internet, that's out of your control.

Using dig:

```
dig@ns1.example.com my.example.com
```

You should see something like:

```
;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.        172800  IN  A   192.0.43.10
```

Just using ping may give you an idea, but only when it has propagated (cached by remote nameservers may be a better way to describe it) and your local dns cache may need to be flushed. Although in your case this does not apply because this is a new record. In that case it should be available immediately. The above way is more precise in giving you an idea as opposed to just pinging it.

If you use windows then the commands and syntax may differ slightly, but are pretty similar.

Comment: +1 If you're doing anything with DNS, get a copy of `dig` (*nix systems already have it, there are various versions for Windows available).

Comment: -1. I'm sorry. I truly am, but this answer "propagates" the myth that DNS records propagate, which they most certainly DO NOT. The term you're looking for is "caching" which is what happens with DNS records, based on the TTL of the record. As the OP is referring to a new DNS record, no caching can have occurred, therefore any DNS client seeking to resolve the record in question will get the answer... immediately... since it can't have been cached by that client... or that clients DNS server... or any other DNS server. DNS records don't propagate to "the rest of the internet".

Comment: joeqwerty's absolutely correct.  dns servers will cache a positive or negative hit for a predefined time.  However, in addition to the original post, there are several public name servers you can check against including the old GTE (4.2.2.1, 4.2.2.2, 4.2.2.3, and 4.2.2.4) and google (8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4). Simple rule of thumb, new changes can take up to the duration of the ttl for positive or negative hit.  However, there are instances where apps implement bad logic and cache answers for a longer period of time.

Comment: I don't think you really have to stick to the exact definition to get a point across. Besides I think that propagating is not a bad word to use. It does cover the subject in the sense that the caching of the DNS record does spread out to a wider range of servers. That spreading out is what propagating refers to. I updated my answer to reflect the fact a new record is available immediately.

Comment: @aseq, it's a misleading term. And it mostly turns out that ppl who think/talk about DNS as kinda "propagation" do not know how DNS works. They usually states a crap like "it takes 2—3 days your DNS information to be propagated across Internet/Earth", and so on.

Comment: If you're talking about your DNS changed being spread to parent/root servers, you can always try: http://cachecheck.opendns.com/

It's global, and I don't think they cache results for long.

Answer (score 7):

You can't test for DNS record propagation because DNS propagation doesn't occur. What you can test for is whether or not a DNS client or server has a particular DNS record cached.

Since this is a new DNS record, no caching can have occured. Assuming that your name servers are correctly registered at the parent servers and that your name servers are working correctly, this DNS record should be available immediately to any and every DNS client or server.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: Is there any way to check that I entered a valid IP? I just wanted to be sure the IP address I used was the right one. Someone I talked to seemed to think that ping would fail if I didn't have an Apache VHost set up yet.

Comment: Ping isn't a DNS testing tool. Dig and Nslookup are DNS testing tools. Use Dig or Nslookup to test the new DNS record. Query for the record against your name server and then query for the record against other name servers to make sure they're finding your name server and that your name server responds with the correct answer.

Comment: "propagation" is a notion made up in case people cannot understand the actual situation, which is cache aging and expiration. What was needed to be said by DNS providers is "your data may not be seen until after XX hours". An explanation of why was needed so it would not look like the DNS provider was the delay. Too many people "cannot handle the truth". The made up "propagation" is an effective cover story. True DNS geeks know what really happens because they read the technical details.

Comment: True enough... I just hate using a term that "propagates" a misconception of how DNS works.

Answer (score 5):

While the other answers are pretty good, remember that what's propagated to you may not be propagated to me.  rather than using DIG or NSlookup and spending an hour checking DNS servers around the world, I usually use http://www.whatsmydns.net/ to see how the propagation is going.

Comment: There's no propagation in DNS, this term is rather misleading for all kind of lamers who won't find themselves reading RFCs, so don't <strike>propagate</strike> use this term, please. ;-D

Comment: Of course there is propagation in DNS the RFCs presume that the reader understands that information can propagate as servers perform lookups and cache.  it's particularly obvious when lamers read RFCs then wonder why a record on their server doesn't match the results of a lookup from a different server.  They discover that propagate has the definition of "to spread widely" (which is exactly what needs to be checked - the distribution of updated records)

Comment: Neither distribution, nor propagation (except master to slave).

Comment: It's probably a relic from when it took sometimes close to a day to get changes made in .com domains loaded on the root nameservers (way back when .com was on the roots!)

Comment: @poige- thanks for verifying your lack of understanding how DNS caching works.  I would suggest reading the RFCs on how DNS works and perhaps checking the website I linked to for real world examples.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to make sure your authoritative DNS servers in your delegation path are answering correctly is to use `dig +trace`:

```
; <<>> DiG 9.7.3 <<>> +trace www.google.com a
;; global options: +cmd
.           80050   IN  NS  m.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  f.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  i.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  h.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  c.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  k.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  d.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  g.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  a.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  b.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  e.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  l.root-servers.net.
.           80050   IN  NS  j.root-servers.net.
;; Received 509 bytes from 192.168.1.1#53(192.168.1.1) in 0 ms

com.            172800  IN  NS  c.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  k.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  g.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  d.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  j.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  f.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  i.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  m.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  e.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  a.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  l.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  h.gtld-servers.net.
com.            172800  IN  NS  b.gtld-servers.net.
;; Received 504 bytes from 198.41.0.4#53(a.root-servers.net) in 127 ms

google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns2.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns1.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns3.google.com.
google.com.     172800  IN  NS  ns4.google.com.
;; Received 168 bytes from 192.43.172.30#53(i.gtld-servers.net) in 20 ms

www.google.com.     604800  IN  CNAME   www.l.google.com.
www.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   173.194.35.180
www.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   173.194.35.178
www.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   173.194.35.176
www.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   173.194.35.177
www.l.google.com.   300 IN  A   173.194.35.179
;; Received 132 bytes from 216.239.34.10#53(ns2.google.com) in 27 ms
```

This will follow the delegations to the nameservers authoritative for your query.  The last answer is normally the one you are most concerned about, but the trace is helpful in that it will show who is answering for each delegation.  If you are changing nameservers, though, this can be very useful.

Keep in mind that trace will query the authoritative servers directly, so there is no caching.  This is the best indication that the answers are being returned as expected, but it is not a good indication of what end-users might experience.  However, since you do not often have control over other peoples' caching nameservers anyway (beyond having the foresight to lower your TTL, wait the original TTL, making the change, then restoring the TTL), it's not usually worth checking after the fact.

Answer (score 2):

Try check-host.net:

http://check-host.net/check-dns?host=example.com%20

The site lets you perform DNS queries through multiple public DNS servers in parallel.  Super handy.